# Help identify story about an overcrowded apartment (maybe from the '70s)?

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

In the story, relatives of a patriarch curry his favor in order to inherit his apartment.It might feature a son/grandson and his expecting wife. Possibly from the '70s. Not Billennium or Roommates, which do share similarities.

Comment: What science fiction or fantasy elements did the story contain?

Comment: Harry, I just found the story. It's Vonnegut's "Tomorrow and Tomorrow and Tomorrow", originally published as "The Big Trip Up Yonder" in the January, 1954 Galaxy Magazine. Thanks so much for helping! Steve Staab

Comment: @user98837 Protocol on Stack Exchange site is for you to make that an answer (yes, to your own question) and (once the wait time elapses) to accept it.

Answer (score 10):

It's Kurt Vonnegut's "Tomorrow and Tomorrow and Tomorrow", slightly revised from ["The Big Trip Up Yonder"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?45753), which was first published in *Galaxy Science Fiction*, January 1954, and is available at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/stream/Galaxy_v07_04_Galaxy_Jan_1954_AKv1.0/Galaxy%20v07%2004%20Galaxy%20%28Jan%201954%29%20%28AKv1.0%29#page/n101/mode/2up).

Description from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tomorrow_and_Tomorrow_and_Tomorrow_%28short_story%29):

> The original story is set in 2185 A.D., 102 years after the invention of a medicine called anti-gerasone, which halts the aging process and prevents people from dying of old age as long as they keep taking it. As a result, the world now suffers from severe overpopulation and shortages of food and resources. With the exception of the wealthy, most of the population appears to survive on a diet of foods made from processed seaweed and sawdust. A cautionary tale, an outside authority figure within the story admonishes the population that "most of the world's ills can be traced to the fact that Man's knowledge of himself has not kept pace with his knowledge of the physical world".
>
> The Schwartz family, headed by 172-year-old Harold ("Gramps"), lives in a three-room apartment on the 76th floor of "Building 257 of Alden Village, New York City, Connecticut". Gramps' grandson Louis, his wife Emerald, and 20 other descendants are crowded into the space, perpetually jockeying for Gramps' favor. Gramps gets the best food and the only private bedroom, and controls everyone's life by constantly revising his will to disinherit anyone who earns his displeasure.
>
> An offhand remark by Lou prompts Gramps to disinherit him and exile Lou and Em to the worst sleeping space in the apartment, near the bathroom. Lou then catches his great-grandnephew, newly wed Mortimer, diluting Gramps' anti-gerasone in the bathroom. Fearing Gramps' reaction to such a scheme, Lou tries to empty the bottle and refill it with the full-strength medicine, but accidentally breaks the bottle and is caught by Gramps, who only tells him to clean up the mess. The next morning, the family finds Gramps' bed empty and a note informing them that he is gone; the note also contains a revised will that bequeaths his entire estate to be held in common by his descendants, with no stipulations as to who receives what property.
>
> A riot breaks out as the family members start fighting over who gets the bedroom, leading to everyone being arrested and jailed at the police station. Lou and Em find the cells to be comfortable and spacious compared to the apartment, and hope that they will be sentenced to prison so they can keep these living arrangements. Meanwhile, Gramps has returned to the now-empty apartment, having watched the events unfold from a tavern across the plaza. He has hired the best lawyer in town in order to get everyone convicted, so that he can have the apartment to himself and they can enjoy the relative comfort of jail for a while. Gramps sees a television commercial for a new product called Super-anti-gerasone, which can reverse the aging process instead of just halting it, and starts thinking about being able to enjoy life again.

Comment: I know you're answering your own question here, but for posterity, it'd be nice if you gave some detail.

Comment: @Vanguard3000 Thanks for the guidance. My first time here.

Comment: No problem. It just helps anyone else who may be looking for the same thing. Welcome to the site!